# android app for upload and aceess the data(from textbox) from intel cloud

Tags: cloud

Can anyone help me to create an android application by which we can upload any small data to ***intel cloud***  and able to access that data form there.
Just write anything may be in a edit text via app, store that on intel cloud 
and access that via another activity in that app form there.